# How to have two functions running simultaneously with python?

Tags: python

I need to run two python functions simultaneously. How can I achieve that? Example:

```py
import time
def short_task():
  time.sleep(2)

def long_task():
  time.sleep(4)

short_task()
long_task()
```

I expect the whole code to finish in 4 seconds (instead of 6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your options is to use the asyncio module.

First of all, import the asyncio module with `import asyncio`. Replace your `def` functions to `async def` functions.

Second of all, replace `time.sleep()` with `await asyncio.sleep()`. You no longer need the time module because of this step.

Thirdly, create a new function, normally called `main()`. You can take the following code snippet for reference:

```py
async def main():
  task1 = asyncio.create_task(
    short_task())
  task2 = asyncio.create_task(
    long_task())
  await task1
  await task2
```

Finally, run the whole `main()` code with `asyncio.run(main())`. Your final code should look like this:

```py
import asyncio
async def short_task():
  await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def long_task():
  await asyncio.sleep(4)

async def main():
  task1 = asyncio.create_task(
    short_task())
  task2 = asyncio.create_task(
    long_task())
  await task1
  await task2
```

You may use a simple code snippet to proof that the whole process took 4 seconds.

Comment: This will achieve the desired result only for nonblocking asynchronous calls (e.g., async-sleep). For CPU-bound or otherwise blocking calls you will probably again end up with sequential execution.

Comment: I don't think you need blocking calls. Just replace all `time.sleep` with `asyncio.sleep` and you are cool.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the functions are doing.

If it is something that involves waiting (such as `time.sleep()` or waiting for a response) use a [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects).

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def short_task():
  time.sleep(2)

def long_task():
  time.sleep(4)

Thread(target=short_task).start()
Thread(target=long_task).start()
```

If you have a long task that requires a lot of computing, use a [Process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process):

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def short_task():
  time.sleep(2)

def long_task():
  time.sleep(4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=short_task).start()
    Process(target=long_task).start()
```

Comment: Before using this, you should be aware of this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock